# Command-line tool to group textual data according to a group key

Tags: linux, text, command-line, grouping

I'd like to find a text-processing utility that would group all the values of an attribute for same primary key. Environment is Linux.

Consider a text file which consist "records", each record being a line in the file. Those records are space-separated sequence of numerical values, one of them being the primary key value, and others being either an additional property of a primary key or attributes computed for this primary key. Example:

> pkey pkey-prop1 pkey-prop2 attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4
>   100 200 400 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
>   100 200 400 0.2 0.7 0.4 0.5
>   100 200 400 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6
>   101 200 401 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
>   101 200 401 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1
>   101 200 401 0.9 1.7 1.1 1.2

By specifying which column plays role of `pkey`, `property` and `attribute`, I'd like to obtain the grouping of a certain attribute from all the records that belong to the same primary key. Example, for `pkey=$1`, `property=$2 $3`, `attribute=$5`, the result would be:

> 100 200 400 0.2 0.7 0.4
>   101 200 401 0.8 0.9 1.7

That is, from all lines with `pkey=100` attributes are grouped into a single line, from all lines with `pkey=101` they are also grouped into another line.

I'm not expecting to have an exact tool, but I'd be very happy to have a tool that does at least grouping.

Comment: yes, awk, assuming it is available. Add a tag to indicate if you;re on Linux/Unix? Good luck

Comment: Yes, environment is Linux, and `awk` is available. But `awk` works like one-line-in->one-line-out, while the task is to many-lines-in->one-line-out. How you think it's possible to do grouping in `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
x==$1 && y==$2 && z==$3 {
    printf(" %s", $5)
    next
}

{
    x=$1
    y=$2
    z=$3
    printf("%s%s %s %s %s", NR==1?"":"\n", x,y,z,$5)
}

END{
    print ""
}' input.txt
```

---

```
100 200 400 0.2 0.7 0.4
101 200 401 0.8 0.9 1.7
```